# JComboBox listing a String from an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that is getting objects that contain user information from a file

once the load is complete, I need the name property from each object to be loaded into a `JComboBox`, so that the user can choose the username to continue.

this conversion from an `ArrayList<object> user --> String[] strName` is where I'm having trouble

any help would be greately appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] values = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

You could just as easily loop through the `ArrayList` and use the `DefaultComboBoxModel's` `addElement` method

Answer (score 0):

There's a good tutorial on how to work with combo boxes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

```
ArrayList<User> users;
int nUsers = users.size();
String[] userNames = new String[nUsers];
for (int i=0;i <nUsers; ++i) {
    User user = users.get(i);
    userNames[i] = user.getName();
}
JComboBox userList = new JComboBox(userNames);
```

If the list is ArrayList<Object> then you'll need to either:

```
// call toString on the object...
userNames[i] = String.valueOf(user);
// or cast it if you know the type
User user = (User)users.get(i);
```